# django login form no css_classes on templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms, django-models

**I need to fetch the css classes for the fields on the forms i'm rendering within a template**. Now according to the docs [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev//topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields) when looping through a form, each item is supposed to be a `BoundField` instance. and also according to the docs [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.css_classes) there should be a css_classes attribute of that instance i can access.

For the generic login view I created the usual `registration\login.html` template. However on the template I can't get any classes to be output and neither do the default labels (`.label_tag`) contain any classes.

heres the form inlude:

```
<div class="default_form">
{{form.non_field_errors}}
<br />
{% for field in form %}
{{field.css_classes}}
<div class="field_container">{{field.label_tag}}{{field}}</div>
<span class="field_help">{{field.help_text}}</span>
<div class="field_errors">{{field.errors}}</div>
<br />
{% endfor %}
```

have i done anything wrong here?

I need the classes for my validation javascripts to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm` or similar, this is probably because `error_css_class` and `required_css_class` [(see docs)](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#styling-required-or-erroneous-form-rows) are not set on the `Form` class.

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
>>> hasattr(AuthenticationForm, 'required_css_class')
False
>>> AuthenticationForm({})['username'].css_classes()
''
>>> class MyForm(AuthenticationForm):
...     error_css_class = 'error'
...     required_css_class = 'required'
...
>>> MyForm({})['username'].css_classes()
'required'
```

You can solve this by subclassing the form like in the example above.

Note that if you wish to use the standard `login` view, you'd need to pass your custom form via the [`authentication_form` argument](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login). E.g. in your `urls.py`:

```
(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', 
    {'authentication_form': MyForm}),
```

Comment: **thanks! it worked**, (babble) although it's frustrating that the classes aren't inserted into the input element. now i have to find a way to manually construct input elements. shouldn't be that hard... i hope. thanks!

Comment: This issue is being actively discussed in [ticket 14710](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14710). If it were me I'd be trying to change my CSS/Javascript to detect the widgets nested within `tr.required` (for example). Injecting the `css_classes` into the widget could be achieved by customising the widget initialisation within the form class, if you really had to.

Comment: I cant believe it's even a discussion.. I think it's something Django unquestionably needed **yesterday**.

Comment: Sorry, what if I want to include the login form on every page? What can I do instead of passing the form to every url? The issue is my registration/login.html doesn't recognize the CSS for django.contrib.auth.views.login and I cannot see {{form.username}} nor {{form.password}}

Comment: @juankysmith: Perhaps look into content processors?